# Copy values from one table to another with 'where' condition

Tags: java, android, sqlite, where-clause

I want to copy values from songDetails table to playlistDetails table.

here is my code :

```
public void transferData(String name) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_CURRENTLIST + " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DATA + " WHERE " + KEY_ALBUMNAME+ " = " + name + "";
    db.execSQL(selectQuery);
}
```

While executing this code, it throws this exception

```
01-31 01:29:49.426: E/AndroidRuntime(3102): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: unknown (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO PlayListDetails SELECT * FROM songDetails WHERE albumName = unknown
```

the value of 'name' variable is correct. And i want to copy only the rows which have the albumName as unknown.
I'm struggled with this. Please help me.

Comment: you missing single quotes around `unknown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing single quotes around query param value (`unknown`).
Your query should be

```
String selectQuery = "INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_CURRENTLIST + " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DATA + " WHERE " + KEY_ALBUMNAME+ " = '" + name + "'";
```

My suggestion would be to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) style parameters.